# Exception when building project with Jenkins Xcode plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to setup a CI using Jenkins for our Unity iOS builds.
The xcworkspace generates just fine, and I'm able to create an archive using Xcode's UI.

When I try building using the Xcode plugin for Jenkins, the build fails. 
I tried creating a dummy project, and got the same error. The plugin docs and Googling aren't leading me anywhere.

I looked up the source of the plugin, and I can't understand why it's breaking. I suspect I'm missing something small, but can't identify it.

```
Working directory is /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/iOSTestApp.
Fetching marketing version number (CFBundleShortVersionString) from project.
[iOSTestApp] $ /usr/bin/agvtool mvers -terse1
No marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) found.
Marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) found in project configuration: 
Fetching technical version number (CFBundleVersion) from project.
[iOSTestApp] $ /usr/bin/agvtool vers -terse
No technical version found (CFBundleVersion)
Technical version (CFBundleVersion) found in project configuration: .
Marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) used by Jenkins to produce the IPA: 
Technical version (CFBundleVersion) used by Jenkins to produce the IPA: 
Read signing information from Xcode Project.
Read information from workspace Builds/iOS/Decisions/Unity-iPhone
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at au.com.rayh.XCodeBuilder._perform(XCodeBuilder.java:1288)
at au.com.rayh.XCodeBuilder.perform(XCodeBuilder.java:1084)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1818)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
```

Using
Xcode: 10.3
MacOS: 10.14.6 (Mojave)
Xcode plugin 2.0.12

[image: SS1]
[image: SS2]
[image: SS3]

Comment: @derHugo - I added screenshots to the settings. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

I created the following plist and saved it on my Desktop

[image: Plist information]

Then i ran the following 3 commands

```
xcodebuild clean -workspace Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace -scheme Unity-iPhone
xcodebuild archive -workspace Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace -scheme Unity-iPhone archivePath Unity-iPhone.xcarchive 
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath Unity-iPhone.xcarchive -exportPath BuildOut  -exportOptionsPlist ~/Desktop/iOSExportOptionsDebug.plist
```

Comment: Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Same with  Xcode 10.3 MacOS 10.14.6 Xcode plugin 2.0.12 but works fine with Xcode 11

UPD: The downgrading Xcode plugin to 2.0.8 was helpful for me

Comment: The downgrading Xcode plugin to 2.0.8 was helpful for me

Comment: XCode 11 + Plugin 2.0.8?

Comment: Face the same problem on Xcode 13, Xcode interation plugin 2.0.15, Any solution?